# Checking for None, False, True

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a more Pythonic way to implement this logic:

```
res = func()

if res is not None:         # res is either True, False, something else
    if res is True:                 
        #do something       # res is True
    elif res is False:                   
        #do something else  # res is False
    else:
        #do something else2 # res is not in [True,False]
else:                       
    #failed                 # res is None
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you already have it covered.

Generally, don't use `is True` or `is False`, if you must have tri-state boolean, use:

```
if res is None:
    # handle None case
elif res:
    # handle true case
else:
    # handle false case
```

e.g. put the burden on the developer to use the tri-state correctly.

If the function needs to communicate more states, you should not use a boolean; in that case switch to using an [enum value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may create a function to map the values to corresponding functions. Something like:

```
# Function to map values
def do_something(res):
    return {
        None: func_1,  # Each `res` mapped to corresponding function
        True: func_2,
        False: func_3,
    }.get(res, func_4)


do_something(res)()
#                ^ call the function returned by `do_something()`
```

The equivalent of the above code can be written based on your logic *mentioned in question* as:

```
if res is not None:
    if res is True:                 
        func_2()     
    elif res is False:                   
        func_3()
    else:
        func_4()
else:                       
    func_1()
```

Comment: For a tri-state, I'd say using a map is overkill. It is certainly not more readable the way you moved everything into a function. You also don't address what should happen if `res` is neither `None` or a boolean object (and you would get an exception in this case). That may be desirable, but please discuss that explicitly.

Comment: Handled the None case returned by `do_something` function. Since OP has made an edit of adding additional condition to else block of first `if`, we may use *default* function with `.get()`

Comment: Better, but I would not call this Pythonic just yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
if res is None: 
    #do something   
elif res:
    #do something else
elif not res:
    #do something else 2
```